# How to substitute user names on a chart with incrementing value except value on a slicer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

The goal is to show what place user currently is  among other users and at the same time hide other user names by substituting their names like `user 1, user 2, user 3` etc.

For example on a snip below "John Smith" is selected on a slicer, so I want to highlight (or possibly change bar color) on his name, and other users' name should be substituted with  `user 1, user 2, user 3` etc.

.pbix could be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hsj7t4p7yh1fhz/TestPowerBI.pbix?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using cross-highlighting:**

Not exactly what you're asking for but you can use a table visual instead of a slicer and turn on [cross-highlighting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-interactions) from the table to the bar chart.

It would look like this when you click on John Smith:

[image: Cross-highlighting example]

---

**Using conditional formatting:**

If you define a separate table for your slicer

```
UserSlicer = VALUES ( Sheet1[UserName] )
```

then you can write a measure to use [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/service-tips-and-tricks-for-color-formatting):

```
Match =
IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Sheet1[UserName] ) = SELECTEDVALUE ( UserSlicer[UserName] ), 1, 0 )
```

[image: Conditional formatting]

Here's what the result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you,. so do you think there is a way to change other users names such `user 1, user 2 ...` when John Smith is selected?

Comment: I think it might be possible to hack a workaround but not easy since you have to use fixed columns on the axis rather than measures.